# Relocating screen origin when zooming in - OPENTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am trying to implement a zooming-in option on a graph by allowing the user to select the area he wants (shown in pic). The graph doesn't take up the whole screen. It ranges from -0.8  to around +1.4 on Y-axis.

[image: Selecting zooming-in area]

After Zooming-in:

[image: After Zooming in]
I do the zooming in by scaling and translating the projection matrix in the `OnRenderFrame` event.

```
Xscale= 1, Yscale=1, Xtrans =0, Ytrans =0;

protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.ClearColor(Color4.Black);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.Count(); j++)
            {
            projection = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -2f, 2.0f);
            Matrix4 Translate = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(Xtrans, Ytrans, 0);
            Matrix4 Scale = Matrix4.CreateScale(1/Xscale, 1/Yscale, 1);
            projection = Translate* Scale* projection;
            view = Matrix4.LookAt(CameraPos,
            CameraPos + CameraFront, CameraUp);
            shader.Use();
            shader.SetMatrix4("model", Matrix4.Identity);
            shader.SetMatrix4("view", view);
            shader.SetMatrix4("projection", projection);
            shader.SetFloat("color", new Vector4(colors.names[i]));
            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO[i]);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, Y1Vertices[0].Count());
            shader.Unbind();
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            }
            SwapBuffers();
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        }
```

I get the scaling factors by finding the ratio between the rectangle dimensions and screen dimensions. For translating, I am trying to find the difference between the rectangle origin and the screen origin then translate the object by this amount. The scaling is working correctly but not the translation. I think maybe the issue is that my object doesn't fill the screen initially, as in doesn't go from -1 to 1 on Y-axis? I am not sure how to account for this offset especially that it changes depending on the graph data. I would also prefer if the zooming in doesn't take up the whole screen and just stays within the initial graph dimensions. Could you please help me out?

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            initialPos = new Vector2(e.X, e.Y);

        }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseMoveEventArgs e)
{
    MouseState mstate = Mouse.GetCursorState();
    if (e.Mouse[MouseButton.Right])
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        newPos = new Vector2(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButton.Right)
    {         
        Xscale *= (Math.Abs(newPos.X - initialPos.X)) / this.Width;
        Yscale *= (Math.Abs(newPos.Y - initialPos.Y) / this.Height);
        Xtrans = (((newPos.X + initialPos.X) / 2)-(this.Width/2))/this.Width;
        Ytrans = (((newPos.Y + initialPos.Y) / 2) - (this.Height / 2)) / this.Height;
    }
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}
```

Edit:

After changing to  `projection = Scale*Translate* projection;`

[image]

Comment: Try scaling before translating. (projection* Scale * Translation)

Comment: The error is actually worse now :/

Comment: `projection = Scale * Translate * projection;` - OpenTK multiplication operator is reversed!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Still getting worse. The offset now is further down although I highlighted the same area as in the first pic.

Comment: You need to define a scale origin. Try translating it towards 0, scaling it, and then translating towards your preferred location.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!